# Quick way to tell if matrix is integer-only?

Tags: matrix

What's the most shortest one-liner code to tell whether a matrix is integer-only?

I've come up with:

```
 Length@Cases[A // Flatten, _?(Not@*IntegerQ)] == 0
```

but isn't there a better, more readable way?

Comment: See MatrixQ[matrix, test].  You can apply a test to each element.

Comment: @Ymareth beat me to it by a minute! :-)

Comment: I did write a bit less :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try this, which is straightforward:

```
A = {{0.5, 1}, {2, 3}};

MatrixQ[A, IntegerQ]
(* False *)
```

Or alternatively - still pretty readable though!

```
ArrayQ[A, _, IntegerQ]
(* False *)
```

This has the added bonus of being applicable to other arrays, for example:

```
integerMatrix = RandomInteger[10, {10, 10, 10}];

ArrayDepth@integerMatrix
(* 3 *)

MatrixQ[integerMatrix, IntegerQ]
(* False *)

ArrayQ[integerMatrix, _, IntegerQ]
(* True *)
```

Building on that, here's a performance test with a big matrix...

```
(* Make a big integer matrix *)
A = RandomInteger[100, {2000, 2000}];

Length@Cases[A // Flatten, _?(Not@*IntegerQ)] == 0 // AbsoluteTiming
(* 2.71 seconds, True *)

MatrixQ[A, IntegerQ] // AbsoluteTiming
(* 0.000005 seconds, True *)

ArrayQ[A, _, IntegerQ] // AbsoluteTiming
(* 0.00001 seconds, True *)
```

Comment: Note that the various array Q functions are optimized for packed arrays.  The timing is independent of the size of the array, I believe, for testing whether it is a packed array of integers or reals.  Hence the performance difference in your last example.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelE2 - I'd just noticed that but wasn't sure why! The comparison was more between these and the OPs example.